# TestNG parallel attribute has no effect on the method execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

i am trying to run the test methods in parallel. The parallel attribute in the testNG xml has no effect on my execution. They runs same for all four possible options (methods,tests,classes,instances).i.e My methods are called in sequential for all the four option.but i need them to run in a parallel fashion. From [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests) i understand the "methods" option should work for me. Any help?

The TestNG xml is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
  <suite name="Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="methods" thread-count="2">
     <test name="parallel">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.sample.A" />
        </classes>
     </test>
  </suite>
```

And the test class is as follow

```
package com.sample;

Class A
{

@Test
public void abc() throws Exception

{
        // some code here

}

@Test
public void xyz() throws Exception

{
        //some code here

}

 }
```

Comment: I never use parallel=methods , because I also never observed it do anything.  Using parallel=classes works fine for me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same TestNG can now execute my methods in parallel. The issue was, though i have changed my xml the TestNG (in Eclipse)run configuration remained same. So i have changed to that to suite XML. Hence the changes made in the XML reflected in my test. Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can see the link
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html


this is my pom 
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${testng.xml}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```